# Unable to type in TinyMCE editor while bootstrap drag and drop

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE in my MVC project. Also using boot strap in it. In website we are using boot strap sort class for drag and drop functionality for div.TinyMCE editor comes under this div.Issue is while drag and drop unable to type in editor and also not retaining already typed content.

Comment: Could you provide some code, or could you develop?

Answer (score 1):

If you drag and drop a DIV that contains TinyMCE you will break the editor as most drag/drop functionality involves removing elements from the DOM and reinserting them in their new locations.

Before the drag process removes the `<textarea>` that sits under TinyMCE you first need to use the TinyMCE `remove()` API to disconnect the editor from the DOM.  After the drag/drop is complete you need to use `init()` to re-instantiate the editor with the new DOM elements.